# how do you upload the apk file in the google play console?

Tags: flutter

This is how my computer looks like

i dont get it.what is an apk file or a google bundle and how do you apload it to the google play console?
i saw that you need the bundle or the apk file to make an android application.

Comment: Your question appears to be missing a screenshot or an image link. Can you add them please? Also, are you following any documentation or tutorial for the task you are trying to accomplish? If so, please link to them in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Go and follow all the steps properly for build an apk or app bundle
[Click here for steps](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android)